# Footer overlap the overlaping divs - CSS

Tags: html, css, css-float

Float Image and div respectively left and right. After float footer was mix with image and div.

## html

```
<img src="images/AboutUs.jpg" class="about_us" alt="about us" />
<div id="description">
djfdjfj
</div>
```

## CSS

```
.about_us {
border: solid 1pt #efefef;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 20px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 20px;
border-top-left-radius: 20px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
width: 30%;
margin-left:  5px;
float: left;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

#description{
background-color: #ffffff;
width: 69.2%; 
float: right;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

footer

```
footer{
width:100%;
border-width:1px 0px 0px 0px;
border-style:solid none none none;
}
```

this is the image [image: mix it up]

What is happening there ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to append this on your footer css

```
footer{
float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should clear float before going to next line. like this

```
 <img src="images/AboutUs.jpg" class="about_us" alt="about us" />
 <div id="description">
   djfdjfj
 </div>
 <div style="clear:float;"></div>
```

or u need to share parent div width to all child float divs without 1px mistake. like this

```
.about_us {width:30%;}
#description{width:70%}
```

try any one which is suitable to you

Answer (score 0):

whenever you float div or images.. then you have to clear So that the other div can't be mixed. Clear property don’t allow floats next to this property.

Example :

```
<div class="main">
<img src="images/AboutUs.jpg" class="about_us" alt="about us" />
<div id="description">
djfdjfj
</div>

<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```